# How do I simplify the following code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have a selection of images and would like a div to appear `on('hover')`. My current code is very bulky and manually adds that div for each of the images.

```
 $("#TheNook").hover(function() {
$("#TheNook-cover").toggleClass("hidden");
});

$("#TheNook-cover").hover(function() {
    $("#TheNook-cover").toggleClass("hidden");
});

$("#ManCave").hover(function() {
    $("#ManCave-cover").toggleClass("hidden");
});

$("#ManCave-cover").hover(function() {
    $("#ManCave-cover").toggleClass("hidden");
});

$("#AnchorsAweigh").hover(function() {
    $("#AnchorsAweigh-cover").toggleClass("hidden");
});

$("#AnchorsAweigh-cover").hover(function() {
    $("#AnchorsAweigh-cover").toggleClass("hidden");
});

$('#BatCave').hover(function() {
    $('#BatCave-cover').toggleClass('hidden');
});

$('#BatCave-cover').hover(function() {
    $('#BatCave-cover').toggleClass('hidden');
});

$('#CountryChic').hover(function() {
    $('#CountryChic-cover').toggleClass('hidden');
});

$('#CountryChic-cover').hover(function() {
    $('#CountryChic-cover').toggleClass('hidden');
});

$('#BohemianBungalow').hover(function() {
    $('#BohemianBungalow-cover').toggleClass('hidden');
});

 $('#BohemianBungalow-cover').hover(function() {
     $('#BohemianBungalow-cover').toggleClass('hidden');
 });
```

My new solution that I have tried is much more condensed, but I'm not entirely sure how to make it work. I'm new to declaring and using variables in JQuery so please help.

```
var cover = $('.theme-img:hover').attr("alt");

$('.theme-img').hover(function() {
    $('#'+cover+'-cover').toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

Here is a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w6pbp4Lz/2/

The first image should behave like the second.

Comment: what is this theme-image class? is this the class of all of the divs?

Comment: That is the class of the images that you must hover over to see the divs.

Comment: Can you include `html` at Question ? , create stacksnippets to demonstrate ?

Comment: added an answer editing your jsfiddle, hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in order to achieve that:

JQUERY:

```
$('img.theme-img').hover(function() {
  $(this).parent().children('div').toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

Here is your JSfiddle with my edits: https://jsfiddle.net/w6pbp4Lz/6/

Comment: Thank you. How would you select the toggled div in the same way? In order to fix the flickering problem when moving over the added div in the fiddle, you have to toggle its hidden class on hover

Comment: $('img.theme-img'.parent().children('div')).hover(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('hidden');
}); I've tried this, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Is the missing bracket after 'theme-img' a typo?

Comment: Yes it was. I fixed it by adding an additional class to the element and then selecting it using that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they all have the class "theme-img" this might work

```
// "var cover = $('.theme-img:hover').attr("alt"); (not needed)

$('.theme-img').hover(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

Comment: The only problem with this is that each div that must be toggled contains unique text. The image you hover over has a class of `theme-img` and unique id and the div that is toggled has a unique id corresponding to whichever image it associates with.

Answer (score 0):

```
function toggleHover(srcElements, tarElement) {
  srcElements.forEach(function(srcElement) {
    srcElement.hover(function() {
      tarElement.toggleClass('hidden');
    });
  });
}
```

call toggle hover with an array of the jQuery elements and the target jQuery element to toggle hidden. example

```
toggleHover([$('#TheNook'), $('#TheNook-cover')], $('#TheNook-cover'));
```

just an idea, might clean the code up a bit